# LuaTeX help setting footer page number from BOTTOM of page

Tags: vertical-alignment, fancyhdr, footer

I need the page number centered vertically and horizontally in the footer space, 1" total height for the footer, baseline of the page number should be 1/2" from the bottom of the page.

I can get all this with `fancyhdr`, but not the consistent height of the pagenumber. I can use `\footskip` to declare where the baseline of the page number should be from the top, but I can't find a way to get it from the bottom. (And in my example, it's also clearly not halfway between text and bottom of the page like it should be anyway)

I'm not trying to cram a ton into the footer, just the page number. And the weird page/margin sizing in the example is required because I'm trying to match the style of a particular book series for my kid.

Sorry it's not a real MWE because I just can't get this number to show up in the right spot. It's driving me a little crazy.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{geometry}[paperwidth=5.25in, paperheight=7.5625in, top=0.8125in, inner=0.8125in, outer =0.6875in, bottom=1in, footskip = .5in]
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\parskip=0pt
\pagestyle{plain}
\cfoot{\normalsize{\thepage}}

\begin{document}
\setstretch{1.3}
\fontsize{15pt}{18pt}\selectfont

\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: the geometry option must be before the {geometry} not after it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Isn't it strange that LaTeX doesn't give an error message on this?

Comment: @PietervanOostrum no, there is an optional argument (for the date).

Comment: Yes, I know, but can that just be anything?